# AWS EC2 Cost comparison in one place?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

Currently having more than twenty AWS accounts and under each account having 6-10 On-demand EC2 instances both Linux and windows of different sizes and types ,altogether around 100 instances . So looking for cost saving options with various options such as Compute Saving Plan, EC2 Saving Plan, Reserve Instance however unable compare of all different options and their estimates side by side.

Though compute and EC2 estimates are given as recommendation through Billing->Cost Explorer but you need to go through each account , then select different option e.c Compute or EC2 saving , then payment options ,then tenure 1 or 3 years and it display estimates .

I want to see all 100 instance and their prices on one page if possible as below

- Under Compute saving plan for 1 and 3 year with full , partial or no upfront payment
- under EC2 saving plan for 1 and 3 years with full , partial or no upfront payment
- Under reserved instance for 1 and 3 year with full , partial or no upfront payment

is there any easier way to get this done ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn’t about programming, but rather the business practices of a commercial service. Questions like this are better addressed by the service provider than by the community.

Comment: Go to the master account and then you can get the recommendation for all by aggrigated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best you can get in terms of what you are looking for:

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From [What is AWS Compute Optimizer? - AWS Compute Optimizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/latest/ug/what-is-compute-optimizer.html):

> AWS Compute Optimizer is a service that analyzes the configuration and utilization metrics of your AWS resources. It reports whether your resources are optimal, and **generates optimization recommendations to reduce the cost and improve the performance of your workloads**. Compute Optimizer also provides graphs showing recent utilization metric history data, as well as projected utilization for recommendations, which you can use to evaluate which recommendation provides the best price-performance trade-off. The analysis and visualization of your usage patterns can help you decide when to move or resize your running resources, and still meet your performance and capacity requirements.
>
> Compute Optimizer provides a console experience, and a set of APIs that allows you to view the findings of the analysis and recommendations for your resources across multiple AWS Regions. **You can also view findings and recommendations across multiple accounts, if you opt in the management account of an organization.** The findings from the service are also reported in the consoles of the supported services, such as the Amazon EC2 console.

Comment: Thank you John . You saved me from pain :)

Answer (score 0):

https://ec2instances.github.io/ tiny opensource tool that pulls pricing data from AWS json-API and presents it as a table.

Disclaimer: I've built this (for myself)